# Flutter Transform classes.jar (project :Dependencies problem) with DexingWithClasspathTransform

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Console Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDAOA.png)

> Transform classes.jar (project :firebase_messaging) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
> ERROR:C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\firebase_messaging\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null

> Transform classes.jar (project :firebase_database) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
> ERROR:C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\firebase_database\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null

> Transform classes.jar (project :firebase_core) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
> ERROR:C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\firebase_core\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null

> Transform classes.jar (project :firebase_storage) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
> ERROR:C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\firebase_storage\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null

> Transform classes.jar (project :firebase_auth) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
> ERROR:C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\firebase_auth\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null

> Transform classes.jar (project :url_launcher_android) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
> ERROR:C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\url_launcher_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null

> Transform classes.jar (project :flutter_local_notifications) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
> ERROR:C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\flutter_local_notifications\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null

> Transform classes.jar (project :image_picker_android) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
> ERROR:C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\image_picker_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null

> Transform classes.jar (project :path_provider_android) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
> ERROR:C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException

> Transform classes.jar (project :printing) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
> ERROR:C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\printing\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
> warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
> warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
> 3 warnings

> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeLibDexDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_database) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersi
> onAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\firebase_database\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_auth) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAt
> tr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\firebase_auth\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_storage) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersio
> nAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\firebase_storage\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_messaging) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVers
> ionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\firebase_messaging\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_core) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAt
> tr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\firebase_core\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :image_picker_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVe
> rsionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\image_picker_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :flutter_local_notifications) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attribute
> s.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\flutter_local_notifications\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :url_launcher_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVe
> rsionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\url_launcher_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :path_provider_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpV
> ersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\munta\StudioProjects\ncc_apps\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :printing) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.
> 3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumen
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s
> 292 actionable tasks: 276 executed, 16 up-to-date
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYD7b.png)

What should I do for this?